# Efficiently eliminate sequential patterns from javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, search

I have an array with a million floats. Caused by a bug in the system supplying the array, the array may contain series of floats pushed twice. This can happen multiple times.

My goal is to eliminate each pattern (serie of floats) that is **immediately followed** by exactly the same pattern.
The pattern length ranges from 32 to 1024.

I have written raw code that removes the contiguous duplicated patterns from the source array and returns an array with activity info.
Work has to be done for edge cases, but it does the job.
But it is very slow.

Here's the code:

```
sequentialSequenceAnnihilator(sourceArray = [], minSequenceLength = 65, maxSequenceLength = 2050) {
    const activityLog = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < sourceArray.length - maxSequenceLength; i++) {
        let searchArray = sourceArray.slice(i+1, i + 1 + maxSequenceLength);
        let searchVal = sourceArray[i];
        let skipIndex = minSequenceLength - 1;
        let searchResult = searchArray.indexOf(searchVal, skipIndex);
        while (searchResult > -1) {
            let isEqual = true;
            let nextOccurrence = i + 1 + searchResult;
            for (let j = 0; j < nextOccurrence - i; j++) {
                isEqual = sourceArray[i + j] == sourceArray[nextOccurrence + j];
                if (!isEqual) break;
            }
            if (isEqual) {
                activityLog.push({
                    index: i,
                    length: nextOccurrence - i,
                    sequence: sourceArray.splice(i, nextOccurrence - i)
                });
                // console.log('sequence starting at ' + i + ' is repeated at ' + nextOccurrence);
                // console.log(sourceArray.splice(i, nextOccurrence - i));
                i = nextOccurrence - 1;
                searchResult = -1;
            } else {
                // searchVal may be part of the sequence; continue search
                skipIndex = searchResult + 1;
                searchResult = searchArray.indexOf(searchVal, skipIndex);
            }
        }
    }
    return activityLog;
}
```

For ease of testing/checking I use an array of integers and a shorter pattern range of 3 to 13.
This is how I tested:

```
const sourceArray = [0,1,2,0,3,4,0,5,0,1,2,0,3,4,0,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,9,8,7,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,7,8,9,3,4,6,2,7,9,2,1,0,4,2,5,6];
const now = new Date();
const activityLog = sequentialSequenceAnnihilator(sourceArray, 3, 13);
console.log('processing time: ' + (new Date() - now));
console.log('[' + sourceArray.join(',') + ']');
```

Given the pattern range of 3 - 13, the duplicated patterns the code should find, are the following bold patterns:
[0,1,2,0,3,4,0,5,**0,1,2,0,3,4,0,5**,1,2,3,4,5,**1,2,3,4,5**,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,9,8,7,1,2,3,4,**1,2,3,4**,6,3,3,3,**3,3,3**,6,3,7,8,9,3,4,6,2,7,9,2,1,0,4,2,5,6]

This should reduce the array to:

```
[0,1,2,0,3,4,0,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,9,8,7,1,2,3,4,6,3,3,3,6,3,7,8,9,3,4,6,2,7,9,2,1,0,4,2,5,6]
```

Contents of the activity log:

```
[
  { "index": 0, "length": 8, "sequence": [0,1,2,0,3,4,0,5] },
  { "index": 8, "length": 5, "sequence": [1,2,3,4,5] },
  { "index": 30, "length": 4, "sequence": [1,2,3,4] },
  { "index": 35, "length": 3, "sequence": [3,3,3] }
]
```

Processing a large array (1M) takes over 20 seconds.

I would like the processing time to be under the 500ms. How can this be achieved? Is there an algorithm I can use?

Comment: Believe you are missing the values `1,2,3,4,5` in the example reduced array beginning at index 8.

Comment: Updated my answer based upon the nuance of finding the duplicated pattern... Also, I think there are at least two ways to increase the performance of your algorithm:  1) Eliminate the `sourceArray.slice(...` and simply reference the `sourceArray` directly, employing `sourceArray.indexOf(searchElement[, fromIndex])` as necessary. This saves copying a slew of array values (ie, 1M * 1024 or 1G floats copied).  2) Possibly make `sourceArray` a typed array of Float32 or Float64 (whatever your case ) which should be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another take.  Essentially it's a two pass solution.

The first pass creates a Map of indexes for each repeated value in the entire array.  For example, using `sourceArray` above, the Map key of `1` will contain the following value array...

- 1: [8, 1, 9, 16, 21, 30, 43, 47, 70, empty × 11]

...with the first value ( `8` ) representing the length of this index (to accommodate pre-allocating the array for performance reasons), and the remaining values identifying all the indexes in `sourceArray` where `1` is found.

The second pass then begins walking `sourceArray`, using the index of the current value to look for possible starting sequences, beginning with the first index value.  Eg, let's say we're at `sourceArray[ 16 ]` which is `1`, and the index array for `1` has an initial value of `1`.  Since index `1` of `sourceArray` is less than `16 + minSeq`, no further check is required, and then the next index value of `9` is checked.  Again, not yet inside the min sequence length.

So finally we come to `21`, which is longer than the min sequence but less than the max sequence, so the next check is to determine if the last characters in both sequences match, before performing a full check of the sequences.  Ie, is `sourceArray[ 20 ] === sourceArray[ 25 ]`?  These match ( ie, 5 === 5 is true ), so a full check is performed between `sourceArray[ 16..20 ]` and `sourceArray[ 21..25 ]` inclusive.  These are found to be equal, so the match is recorded. The algorithm then, of course, moves onto `sourceArray[ 26 ]` and repeats the process...

The result of this algorithm is a list of matching consecutive sequences, and does not recreate the final array, as there is no sense in performing this final step if, for instance, the purpose is to dump the results to a file.  In that case, walking both the list of matches and the `sourceArray` concurrently can save an entire full scan of the million floats...

**EDIT:  Updated code to properly reflect need to check for sequences from min sequence to max sequence rather than vice versa.**

```js
const sourceArray = [0,1,2,0,3,4,0,5,0,1,2,0,3,4,0,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,9,8,7,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,7,8,9,3,4,6,2,7,9,2,1,0,4,2,5,6];

function createIndex( arr, minSeq, initialArraySize ) {

  result = new Map(); 
  
  for ( let i = 0; i < arr.length - minSeq + 1; i++ ) {
    let index = result.get( arr[ i ] );
    if ( index === undefined ) {
      index = [];
      index.length = initialArraySize;
      index[ 0 ] = 0;
      result.set( arr[ i ], index );
    }
    index[ ++index[ 0 ] ] = i;
  }
  
  return result;

}

function findSequences( arr, index, minSeq, maxSeq ) {

  function fullCheck( i0, i1 ) {
    let i = i0;
    let len = i1 - i0;
    while ( i < i1 && arr[ i ] === arr[ i + len ] ) {
      i++;
    }
    return ( i === i1 );
  }

  let result = [];
  
  for ( let i = 0; i < arr.length - minSeq + 1; i++ ) {

    let indexList = index.get( arr[ i ] );
    let nMax = indexList[ 0 ];
    let n = 1;
    while ( n <= nMax && indexList[ n ] <= i + maxSeq ) {
      let ni = indexList[ n ];
      if ( i + minSeq <= ni ) {
        if ( arr[ ni - 1 ] === arr[ ni + ( ni - i ) - 1 ] && fullCheck( i, ni ) ) {
          result.push( { lo: i, hi: ni, len: ni - i } );
          i = ni + ( ni - i ) - 1;  //final "-1" to accommodate "for" loop.
          break;
        }
      }
      n++;
    }
  
  }
  
  return result;

}

// Tune initialArraySize accordingly...
index = createIndex( sourceArray, 3, 20 );
console.log( index );

x = findSequences( sourceArray, index, 3, 13 );
console.log( x )
```

I have not timed this, but am interested in the performance you see with the 1M floats that you have...

Comment: I've ran the code on appr. 900k floats and that lasted 36s, against 43s on a slow testing VM. Using an average PC this will be 3-4 times faster. I will update the question itself about the processing.

Comment: @PeterDr thanks for clarifying the process, as my original algorithm was searching for the max sequence down to the min sequence rather than vice versa.  Code has been updated, and now matches your sample results.  (Note though that the "activity log" that I generate assumes a non-mutating `sourceArray`.)